# Información sobre base de datos y java

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de utilizar una base de datos en una aplicación Java? ¿Es necesario utilizar un framework como Hibernate o simplemente utilizar las queries directamente en Java con los objetos `Statement`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a explicarte como trabajo yo con la base de datos para que te des una idea del proceso y luego te paso un link con algo de información que encontré sobre hibernate.

Normalmente se utiliza el conector de la base que vas a utilizar. Por ejemplo, para MySQL utilizas MySql Connector que viene ya listo en NetBeans (Es el JDBC), solo basta agregarlo al proyecto.

Después creas tu clase conexión para facilitarte el trabajo. Este es un ejemplo que suelo utilizar.

```
private boolean Miconexion(){
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        this.connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"
                +ConexionDatos.URL_SERVIDOR
                +ConexionDatos.BD,
                ConexionDatos.USUARIO_SERVIDOR,
                ConexionDatos.CONTRASENA_SERVIDOR);
} 
    catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
       //AQUÍ EL MENSAJE DE ERROR POR SI FALLA. 

    return false;
}
```

`DriverManager.getConnection` devuelve un tipo `Connection` y este a su vez se ejecuta para devolver el statement.

Yo personalmente utilizo MVC (Modelo, Vista, Controlador) donde mi modelo tiene las Clases VO, DAO e IT(Esta última es un churro mío). VO (Value object se encarga de almacenar todos los datos de la tabla. Por ejemplo tienes la tabla Persona:

> Persona:
>   -Id
>   -Nombre.
>   -Edad.

En tu proyecto, tendrias por lo menos dos Clases PersonaVo y PersonaDao y en mi caso PersonaIT.

Tu clase PersonaVo seria sumanente sencilla.

```
public class PersonaVo {

    String persona;
    int edad;
    int id;

    public int getId() {
       return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
         this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPersona() {
        return persona;
    }

    public void setPersona(String persona) {
        this.persona = persona;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

}
```

Esta sirve para transportar todos tus datos de la tabla. Cada vez que necesitas guardar, modificar, o consultar algún dato de la tabla creas una nueva instancia.

Después esta PersonaDao:

```
public class PersonaDao {

    public List<PersonaVo> consultarTodo(){
        //CONSULTA TODOS LOS DATOS DE LA BASE DE DATOS.
        //AQUI VAN LAS SENTENCIAS SQL.
    }

    public void eliminarUnRegistro (int id){
        //SENTENCIA PARA ELIMINAR UN REGISTRO. 
    }

    public void agregarRegistro(PersonaVo vo){
       //SENTENCIA PARA AÑADIR UN REGISTRO.
    }



}
```

Todas las sentencias SQL se ejecutan únicamente dentro de DAO. Esto te permite un mantenimiento mucho más fácil de la tabla y mayor orden.

La clase PersonaIT (Que esta fuera de cualquier patrón que conozca) almacena la información de cada campo de la tabla. De manera que si el campo id es autoincrement, no permite nulos (por obvias razones), es tipo int, etc, entonces lo almaceno en PersonaIT junto con un campo que almacene el nombre de la columna y después lo relaciono. Esto sirve para hacer validaciones automáticas despues. Si hay algún cambio en la base de datos solo tienes que modificar estas clases para que se ajusten.

Bueno, todo este trabajo rinde frutos cuando el proyecto es largo. Para proyectos cortos es mucho más lento.

Sobre hibernate se que es algo similiar, solo que en vez de trabajar el IT que yo tengo utiliza XML y genera identidades. En este aspecto estoy muy corto y no sabría como explicarte más.

Estoy leyendo esto y tal vez te puedas documentar más:

http://www.javatutoriales.com/2009/05/hibernate-parte-1-persistiendo-objetos.html

Y sobre MVC te recomiendo:

http://codejavu.blogspot.mx/2013/06/ejemplo-modelo-vista-controlador.html

La respuesta que @Carlos da es muy buena para ampliar las bondades de cada uno. Siempre he trabajado con JDBC puesto que venia de manejar directamente la tabla y no me ha costado tanto. En cambio como comenta Carlos el aplicar algo que no conoces solo te traerá frustración. Empieza por lo que más conozcas y poco a poco vas ampliando tu conocimiento.

Answer (score 2):

Si conoces el framework y tu sistema es complejo, lo mejor sería utilizar las ventajas que te ofrecen los frameworks. Caso contrario, la comunicación a la base de datos con jdbc, utilizando los Statement funciona de maravilla, y no es engorroso la implementación. 
En mi trabajo no utilizo ningún framework, y la comunicación a la base es sencilla de mantener.

**HIBERNATE**

**Ventajas**

- Nos permite desarrollar mucho mas rápido.
- Permite trabajar con la base de datos por medio de entidades en vez de Querys.
- Nos ofrece un paradigma 100% orientado a objetos.
- Elimina errores en tiempo de ejecución.
- Mejora el mantenimiento del software.

**Desventajas**

- No ofrece toda la funcionalidad que ofrecería tirar consultas nativas.
- La performance es mucho mas baja que realizar las consultas por JBDC.
- Puede ser más tediosos el aprendizaje de la tecnología.

**JDBC**

**Ventajas**

- Ofrece un performance superior ya que es la forma mas directa de mandar instrucciones la base de datos.
- Permite explotar al máximo las funcionalidades de la base de datos.

**Desventajas**

- El mantenimiento es mucho mas costoso.
- Introduce muchos errores en tiempo de ejecución.
- El desarrollo es mucho mas lento.

Por más que **Hibernate** parezca mejor por la cantidad de ventajas que ofrece, las desventajas que tiene son muy serias y pueden ser cruciales a la hora de decidir que tecnología utilizar ya que si tenemos una aplicación muy buena y fácil de mantener pero que tarda demasiado para consultar datos puede llegar a ser algo muy malo.

Como conclusión yo diría que si requieres una aplicación donde el rendimiento sea el factor mas importante utilices **JDBC**, pero por otra parte si el rendimiento es algo que no están importante puedes utilizar **Hibernate**.